# How to get current layout in app.razor file

Tags: routes, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following code within my app.razor

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    <NotAuthorized>
        SOME CODE HERE
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```

Is there a way to add an if statement to check for the current layout? Something like this:

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
    if (currentlayout == layoutname) {
        <NotAuthorized>
            SOME CODE HERE
        </NotAuthorized>
    }
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```